# Vimscript code highlighting

Tags: discussion

I just noticed this today and don't have a link to any official status changes that indicate this would be supported.

I think you can use `lang-vimscript` after a triple-backtick code fence to get highlighting (it doesn't seem to be working on this meta site, but should work on the main site).

Comment: Oh nice! Annoyingly, I've been marking up all mine with `vim` since they changed highlighting backends. (Can't remember why I thought that would end up being the supported syntax, but I definitely had some reason for it.)

Comment: Is this just a synonym for `lang-vim` or do they differ in anything?

Comment: @Friedrich frankly I have no idea. I’ll ask around.

Comment: After a little trial and error, I haven't noticed any difference between `lang-vim` and `lang-vimscript`. What I did notice was that `"` is always interpreted as belonging to a string, not a comment which makes properly commented code awkward to read. Is there any place where one could report this bug?

Comment: Is it for vim9 or for vim8. I have used it at  this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42032/how-to-automatically-close-all-the-terminal-buffers-when-closing-vim-with-qa/42034#42034) and the result looks odd.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt the "zebra" comments are caused by quotes being evaluated in pairs as string delimiters as I commented above. Other than that, your post looks almost okay. Would be nice if e.g. `endif` was recognized as a keyword, too.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I hijacked [your answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42032/how-to-automatically-close-all-the-terminal-buffers-when-closing-vim-with-qa/42034#42034) and appended quotes to every comment line. It looks a bit more reasonable now (apart from my superfluous quotes, obviously).

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich my goal was to know or to exemplify how much the lang-vimscript seems not to be working.

Comment: @Friedrich bugs go to highlight.js: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Seems highlight.js works fine on its own so I asked on meta: [Syntax highlighting for Vimscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394497/syntax-highlighting-for-vimscript).

Comment: According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394499/931362) answer it seems `vimscript` is not yet supported or at least the hint is not.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `lang-vimscript` and `lang-vim` are not supported. It *looks like* they were supported, but they're not.

See this answer for [Language codes currently available on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/753726). It is updated when new languages are added and (at the time of this writing) there's no `vim` on the entire page.

#### Short explanation

When SE does not know a language hint, it will just silently pick one on it's own. In [Vivian's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42032/how-to-automatically-close-all-the-terminal-buffers-when-closing-vim-with-qa/42034#42034), it randomly goes for C# highlighting. This is a known problem across SE sites: [Stop guessing/auto-detecting a language when you KNOW it will be incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355852)

Quoting from above question

> It makes users think a language is supported when it is not

I couldn't agree more.

#### Long explanation

See my question on meta: [Syntax highlighting for Vimscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394497/syntax-highlighting-for-vimscript) and [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394499/753726) given by [zcoop98](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/776523/zcoop98).

Zcoop98 suggested making a "formal request" for Vimscript to be added but chances seem to be slim. I'll see what I can do.

By the way, highlight.js does support `lang-vim` (with some quirks) so it's just a matter of enabling that feature on SE.

#### Conclusion

For now, I think it's better to go without any language hint. No highlighting is still preferable to wrong highlighting.

Comment: I’ve edited the OP to be less confusing in light of this. Thanks for the research